# Две вложенные таблицы одинаковой высоты

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Проблемы вёрстки. Есть таблица - контейнер. У неё одна единственная строчка, в которой содержится две ячейки. В каждой ячейке ещё по таблице. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы высота одной таблицы вычислялась в зависимости/так же как и высота другой.

```css
.table_container {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Убираем двойные линии между ячейками */
  margin: 5px 15px;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgba(86,100,115,1);
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
.table_container td {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.table_container .inner_table {
  height: 90%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Убираем двойные линии между ячейками */
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.table_container .inner_table td {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(86,100,115,1);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table_container .inner_table th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(86,100,115,1);
}
.table_container .inner_table th p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="matrioshka-tables">
  <table class="table_container">
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <table class="inner_table" style="width: 650px; height: inherit;">
            <tr>
                <td>FJIREHT943TH0-34934943-435N8Y3Y34Y3Y4</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <table class="inner_table" style="width: 190px; height: inherit;">
            <tr>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Some</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>bnbkj</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Во внутренних таблицах все ячейки строго заданной ширины для того, чтобы свойство **table-layout: fixed** могло работать. 
С высотой заранее не угадаешь. Проблема в том, что если в одной таблице высота строк растягивается в зависимости от содержимого, в другой этого не происходит, и она становится меньше первой, хотя в идеале требуется, чтобы они воспринимались как одна общая таблица. Можно ли как-то разрешить эту проблему?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что Вам надо, чтобы высота обеих `.inner_table` была одинаковой вне зависимости от содержимого? Другими словами, вы хотите выровнять именно внутренние таблицы?

Comment: И еще вопрос: вот этот `div`: `<div style="width: 100%; height: inherit;">` - он необходим? похоже, что именно он источник проблем

Comment: @cyadvert, я понял, что он хочет синхронизировать высоту строк внутренних таблиц, а не высоту самих внутренних таблиц.

Comment: Высоту строк? `line-height`??? Автор, пожалуйста, уточните.

Comment: @cyadvert, да, необходимо синхронизировать высоту строк, а, соответственно, и высоту обеих внутренних таблиц. Так как если высота строк каждой из таблиц будет одинакова, то и высоты таблиц так же будут одинаковы.

Comment: `если высота строк каждой из таблиц будет одинакова, то и высоты таблиц так же будут одинаковы`. не совсем так... если в одной таблице 5 строк текста, а в другой - 3 строки текста, то при условии, что высота строк одинаковая, высота таблиц будет разная

Comment: @cyadvert, в моём случае такой ситуации не будет.

Comment: т.е. у вас две таблицы, одна шириной 950px, вторая - 190px; и вы 100% уверены, что кол-во строчек текста в них будет всегда одинаково? однако высота строчки в одной ячейки будет меняться, и соответственно должна меняться высота другой. так?

Comment: @cyadvert, да, именно так.

Comment: @cyadvert, если вы сейчас попробуете выполнить представленный выше код, вы увидите суть проблемы. Ширина правой таблицы поменялась и не воспринимается как продолжение левой таблицы.

Comment: Все, я понял. Мы говорили о разных строчках. Я спрашивал про высоту строчек текста, а Вы говорили про строки таблиц...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30260/discussion-between-cyadvert-and-neo).

Answer (score 3):

> Проблема в том, что если в одной таблице высота строк растягивается в зависимости от содержимого, в другой этого не происходит, и она становится меньше первой, хотя в идеале требуется, чтобы они воспринимались как одна общая таблица.

Тогда и надо сделать одну таблицу. Зачем мудрить-то?

Comment: раз есть две таблицы, значит это было сделано по практической необходимости.

Comment: @neo, http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178988

Answer (score 2):

**Задание:**
есть две таблицы с одинаковым количеством строк. Таблицы расположены рядом друг с другом, но высота строк разная.
Задача, выровнять высоты строк так, чтобы две таблицы выглядели как одна.

**Описание решения:**
 1. сверяем высоты таблиц и выясняем, которая выше
 2. для каждой строки большей таблицы выясняем высоту
 3. присваиваем эту высоту соответствующей строкe второй таблицы

Также потребуются небольшие изменения в CSS: для правильного подсчета сделать бордюр `border-box`.

**Решение:**
CSS:

```
.table_container .inner_table td {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

JS:

```
function evenTables() {
    var fstTable = $('.inner_table').eq(0); // первая таблица
    var secTable = $('.inner_table').eq(1); // вторая таблица
    // сравниваем высоты таблиц и определяем 'из' и 'в' таблицы
    if (fstTable.height()>secTable.height()) {
        var source = fstTable;
        var dest = secTable;
    } else {
        var source = secTable;
        var dest = fstTable;
    }
    // прокручиваем через все строчки таблицы 'из'
    // выясняем высоты первых ячеек каждой строки
    // присваиваем выясненное значение первым ячейкам соответствующих строк таблицы 'в'
    source.find('tr>td:first-child').each(function(ind, el) {
        setHeight = $(el).outerHeight(true);
        dest.find('tr:nth-child(' + (ind+1) + ')>td:first-child').outerHeight(setHeight);
    });
});
evenTables();
```

Решение было проверено на Chrome, FF, Opera, IE.

Comment: огромное спасибо за предложенное решение, обязательно попробую!

Comment: @neo, а если сравнить его с набором поставленных тобою тегов?

Comment: @cyadvert, каким образом можно расширить это решение на обработку не только тега td, но и th?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Поставить вместо `td` - `th` внутри `.find()`

Answer (score 0):

Задайте всем ячейкам таблицы и вложенным таблицам `height: 100%;`:

```
.table_container td {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
.table_container .inner_table {
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Убираем двойные линии между ячейками */
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Comment: И у вас здесь `<table class="inner_table" style="width: 950px; height: inherit;>` кавычки не хватает

Comment: не помогло((((((((

Comment: Я уже поняла, что вам нужно не только таблицы одинаковой высоты, а еще и ячейки, чтобы совпадали, а это уже только js.

Answer (score 0):

Если не использовать javascript, то можно пойти по пути наследования классов используя свойство **inherit** - наследование от родительского элемента, но я не уверен на все сто процентов, что это сработает.

А с помощью javascript'a можно брать айди обоих таблиц, сравнивать их значения характеристик высоты и айди с меньшим значением назначать значение большего айди. Простенькая **if**-**else** конструкция.

Код нужен?

Comment: пробовала через наследование - не сработало.

Comment: А !important если добавить?

Comment: Да не выйдет же. Динамическая высота. Либо одна таблица, либо скрипты.