# Одинаковые ячейки таблиц

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Не могу реализовать одну идею. Есть таблицы, при описании текста в ячейки, ячейки увеличиваются, а у остальных таблиц нет, мне нужно, чтобы ячейки и в остальных таблицах тоже увеличивались (не только первого столбца), их может быть много и в этих столбцах тоже ячейки должны увеличиваться.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

<sub>*Был подобный вопрос уже был задан, но там код работает не так, как нужно мне.*</sub>

Comment: Прошу добавьте хотя бы визуализацию вопроса в виде рисунка в паинте, иначе переформулируйте вопрос. если я правильно понял (что вряд-ли), попробуйте создать новый класс и повесить его на все ячейки всех таблиц, а в нем реализовать свойства расширения этих таблиц по размеру максимального контента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, что Вам подойдёт вариант с одной таблицей, но с несколькими секциями `<tbody>` (JS здесь, только для того, чтобы размножить секции, добавить интерактивность и не писать "простыню" HTML) :

```js
/* For example only --> */ let table = document.querySelector('table'), tbody = document.querySelector('tbody'); for (let i = 2; i < 4; i++) { let clone = tbody.cloneNode(true); clone.querySelector('th[colspan]').textContent = `Таблица ${i}`; table.append(clone); } table.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(el => el.contentEditable = true);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }

tbody { box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #000;}
tbody:not(:last-of-type)::after { content: ""; display: block; padding: 1em; }

th { padding: 0.5em; box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 #000; background-color: #0004; }
th:first-of-type { box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 #000, inset 1px 0 0 #000; }

td { padding: 0.5em; box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 #000; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th colspan="5">Таблица 1</th></tr>
    <tr><th></th><th>Колонка 1</th><th>Колонка 2</th><th>Колонка 3</th><th>Колонка 4</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Строка 1</th><td>Попробуйте</td><td>изменить</td><td>текст в этих</td><td>ячейках</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Строка 2</th><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, ваш вариант очень хороший. Но увы, мне нужно чтобы таблицы были так же взаимосвязаны, если они будут находиться в html(увы мне так нужно), редактирование не понадобиться, данные таблицы будут подставляться из другой части кода, мне нужно любого вида таблица(хоть с титульным заголовком, хоть без, так как я заметил, что без титульного заголовка, выдает ошибку). И в моем случаи будет коллекция таблиц, по этому придется через quleselectorALL обращаться к ним(надеюсь вы понимаете о чем я), а так да, это фактически то функционал который мне нужен был. Надеюсь на взаимопонимание.

Comment: Не могли бы сделать изменения, которые я указал.

Comment: Этот вариант тоже сойдет, я там немного пошаманил и получилось то что нужно. Спасибо в любом случаи, хранит вас бог.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял вам скорее нужен JavaScript, на одном только css у вас не получиться так сделать. Так как вам нужно динамически меня размер не связанных ячеек.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```js
let table = document.querySelectorAll("table");
let max = 0;

for (let temp = 0; temp < table.length; temp++) {
  let tbody = table[temp].querySelector("tbody");

  for (let i = 0; i < tbody.children.length; i++) {
    let tr = tbody.querySelectorAll("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < tr[i].children.length; j++) {
      if (tr[i].children[j].offsetWidth > max) max = tr[i].children[j].offsetWidth;
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < tbody.children.length; i++) {
    let tr = tbody.querySelectorAll("tr");
    for (let j = 0; j < tr[i].children.length; j++) {
      tr[i].children[j].style.width = max + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Таблица 1</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>Длинее всех</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1>Таблица 2</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1>Таблица 3</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
    <td>asd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Это не совсем то. Смотрите, как я ранее сказал, к примеру у нас есть 5 таблиц, к примеру мы добавляем текст в 1 таблицу 1 столбец и какую то ячейку(но может и не только в 1, в любую), ячейки увеличиваются, надо чтобы эти изменения из 1 таблицы(К примеру) применились к остальным таблицам(добавили текст = ячейки колонки куда добавлен текст увеличился и то же самое должно и в других таблицах(грубо говоря остальные таблицы = таблице где произошли изменения)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457084/Две-вложенные-таблицы-одинаковой-высоты что то подобное что и здесь, но там только первые колонки изменяются, а надо чтобы и другие так же работали(увеличивались, но не увеличивались, так как в вашем примере(они у вас все увеличиваются). P.S - у меня коллекция таблиц, по этому там через цикл их надо прогонять скорее всего.

Comment: Изменил, если что пишите

Comment: Я позже отвечу, подойдет такой вариант или нет. В любом случаи, суть вы уловили.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Я хотел бы чтобы увеличивались не все ячейки(из всех столбцов), а в том где произошло изменение. Примеру произошли изменения в 1 колонке, остальные остаются так же без изменения.

Comment: Тобишь, в 1 колонке произошло изменение, ячейки в 1 столбце во всех таблицах увеличились, остальные остались колонки без изменения и так далее с остальными колонками в таблицах. Чтобы ширина была разная, а не равная

Comment: Ваш вариант тоже хороший, я его тоже использовал в другом проекте. Спасибо за помощь. Да хранит вас бог.